# Не отображается добавленный заголовок "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

Tags: c#, сервер

Добавил заголовок request.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"), в консоле все норм, в инспекторе браузера ничего не отображается.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавили заголовок где? В какой консоли норм? Почему браузер должен слать свое реквесты с вашими заголовками?

Comment: Судя по коду - вы добавили на сервере, в request. А проверяете ответ от сервера, response.

Comment: Добавил заголовок в коде проекта, если выводить в VS в консоль, то все заголовки отображаются как и должны, но в инспекторе брвузера не весь список заголовков. Или я чего то не понимаю ?

Comment: вы чего то не понимаете. Отправка вами в коде запросов не то же самое, что отправка запросов браузером. Если вы в своем коде добавляете чт то при отправке запросов, браузеру это до лампочки

Comment: На сервере, request - это то, что пришло от клиента. То, что уйдет клиенту - это response. `request.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")` -> `response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")`

Comment: Большое спасибо что объяснили.